# This modification is not allowed, because the selection is locked

Tags: office-2013

Office 2013 doesn't let me write anything inside my word document!
It shows me the following message:

> This modification is not allowed, because the selection is locked.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the message was coming up on a single element of the document and was connected with the template I was using. I was trying to remove a field referring to the manager of the project from a single page of the document. When I would highlight and press "delete" I would see the message "this-modification-is-not-allowed-because-the-selection-is-locked".

I resolved the issue by highlighting the section and on the "developer" tab selecting "properties". A pop-up would open titled "content control properties" within which I could deselect the option "content control cannot be deleted".
I was then able to delete the object.

Comment: FYI you may need to enable the Developer 

File > Options > Customize Ribbon > tick Developer

Comment: this worked for me. if there is a section restriction and it doesn't show up in Word Restriction options, there's a fair chance you have a custom built control flagged as not deletable (to create a dropdown list of options for example)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because your **Microsoft Office** is not activated. Try to activate it with the key. If you don't have it then install another Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this message was coming up on a single element in the document - A text field called "Title".

[image: The Document Title]

It was absolutely uneditable, while the rest of the document was unprotected and could be changed. My solution was going into the document properties, under the file menu, and changing the title there.

[image]

In this case, this is actually the metadata that is stored with the file.

Hopefully this helps other people who run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the free license is expired. You will have to buy the software key. Or use alternatives like LibreOffice(Opensource), OpenOffice(Opensource) and WPS office.